# How to bind the type variable of a method that can only be statically imported?

Tags: java, generics, import

I have two classes called `Matchers` with static methods that I need to use in a third class, so one of them can only be used via static imports. However, I cannot explicitly specify type parameters (i.e. `<Type> method()`) for statically imported methods.

How can I work around this without having to fully qualify the class?

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not sure how to give an example in this case... I basically want to call `Matchers.<T> method()`, but `Matchers` is already imported as a different class.

Comment: `How can I work around this without having to fully qualify the class?` You cannot. At least, not AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. At least not in Java (some other languages, for instance Scala, let you give an alias to a class you import which is kind of cool and can be used exactly in such a case).

Here you just need to either use the fully qualified name for both classes or for one class (and import the other one).

Using 2 classes with the same name in one file isn't the best idea unless you have a really good use case for it. Maybe you can actually do what you want using only one of the Matchers?

I'm going to do some mind reading here but I'd guess this is something along the lines of Hamcrest/Mockito Matchers? If so then in most cases you should be ok with using only one of them. If you're in the very unfortunate case where you **do** need both then, well, you're unfortunate :-)

Comment: Yes, it's actually Hamcrest matchers. I made the bad decision to implement a class called `Matchers` as well, which caused this. Unfortunately, the name can no longer be changed as it's part of the API.

Comment: well then unfortunately you're in the unfortunate position :-) Unless the API cannot be broken or "bumped to a higher version" which would change the name of your class, then the best advice I can give you is to import the Matchers class with the longer fully qualified name so your code will be a bit less cluttered :-)

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a very hacky way just as an alternative to fully qualifying the class:

Simply implement a sub-class of class in question and call the parent class static method on the sub-class. This is allowed and does not even generate compiler warnings. Since the method is static, no virtual method stuff is involved. The sub-class simply serves as an alias (so better make it private and final and stuff).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that might look a bit unclean but it’s covered by the standard. You can abuse local variables as imports. Since their value doesn’t matter for `static` method invocations they can be initialized to `null`

```
public class Imports
{
  static <T> java.util.List<T> emptyList()
  {
    System.out.println("Imports.emptyList()");
    return java.util.Collections.emptyList();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final java.util.Collections c=null;
    final Imports i=null;
    System.out.println(c.emptyList());
    System.out.println(i.emptyList());
  }
}
```

`c.emptyList()` and `i.emptyList()` refer to different `static` methods here. And you may even insert type arguments, e.g. `c.<String>emptyList()`. But some compilers might issue warnings you have to switch off for a class using this trick. But in some cases there might be no better way (repeating qualified names lots of times is not always a better way)…